# Resolve Class file for java.util.function.Function not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar, stanford-nlp

I want to use the Stanford POS-tagger in my android project.

I added the pos-tagger .jar files to my android project in Android Studio:

- slf4j-api.jar
- slf4j-simple.jar
- stanford-postagger-3.6.0.jar

I can import the library correctly:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;
```

But an error occurs when I use the function tagString:

```
MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("model/english-left3words-distsim.tagger");
String tagged = tagger.tagString("Hello World");//--->>ERROR
Log.i("tags",tagged);
```

When compiling, I am getting the error:

> Error:(34, 31) error: cannot access Function class file for
> java.util.function.Function not found Error:Execution failed for task
>
> ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

How can I use the stanford pos-tagger in my Android project correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you compiling with Java 8? Recent versions of CoreNLP require Java 8; the error you're seeing is likely from the compiler not finding the newly introduced `Function` class.

Comment: helped me finding the solution. i compiled with 8, which seemed incompatible with current coreNLP. using the last corenlp version for java 7 worked.